# Show and hide tooltip on click (Tipso.js)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, tooltip

I'm using simple tooltip plugin called [Tipso](https://tipso.object505.com/).
How can I show and hide tooltips only by click?

```js
$('.top').tipso();
```

```css
/* Tipso Bubble Styles */

.tipso_bubble,
.tipso_bubble>.tipso_arrow {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tipso_bubble {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.tipso_style {
  cursor: help;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

.tipso_title {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.tipso_content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0.5em;
}


/* Tipso Bubble size classes - Similar to Foundation's syntax*/

.tipso_bubble.tiny {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.small {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.default {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.large {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Tipso Bubble Div */

.tipso_bubble>.tipso_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tipso_bubble.top>.tipso_arrow {
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.bottom>.tipso_arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.left>.tipso_arrow {
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.right>.tipso_arrow {
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble .top_right_corner,
.tipso_bubble.top_right_corner {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .bottom_right_corner,
.tipso_bubble.bottom_right_corner {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .top_left_corner,
.tipso_bubble.top_left_corner {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .bottom_left_corner,
.tipso_bubble.bottom_left_corner {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tipso.object505.com/tipso.js"></script>


<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <span class="top tipso_style" data-tipso="This is a tooltip text">I want to show the tooltip on click and hide it on click as well.</span>
</div>
```

[View on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uk2hefpc/)

Comment: Alternatively, [Tooltipster](https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) looks pretty robust and supports [click/touch triggering](https://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#demo-touch).

Comment: I did try it first, but I didn't notice that it has `minWidth` and other styling options. Now I'm thinking about switching back :) Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider adding a `click` handler that shows or hides the tooltip depending on whether it's already showing. [Tipso documentation](https://tipso.object505.com/) recommends using a class to indicate when the tooltip is showing; see the demo titled "Click to show/hide tipso".

Here's a demonstration of a click event that toggles the tooltip. It also includes `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers to update the "showing" class.

```js
$('.top')
  .tipso()
  .on({
    mouseenter: function(e) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('typso-showing');
    },
    mouseleave: function(e) {
      jQuery(this).removeClass('typso-showing');
    },
    click: function(e) {
      let $this = jQuery(this);
      if ($this.hasClass('typso-showing')) {
        $this.removeClass('typso-showing');
        $this.tipso('hide');
      } else {
        $this.addClass('typso-showing');
        $this.tipso('show');
      }
    }
  });
```

```css
/* Tipso Bubble Styles */

.tipso_bubble,
.tipso_bubble>.tipso_arrow {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tipso_bubble {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.tipso_style {
  cursor: help;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

.tipso_title {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.tipso_content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0.5em;
}


/* Tipso Bubble size classes - Similar to Foundation's syntax*/

.tipso_bubble.tiny {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.small {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.default {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.large {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Tipso Bubble Div */

.tipso_bubble>.tipso_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tipso_bubble.top>.tipso_arrow {
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.bottom>.tipso_arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.left>.tipso_arrow {
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.right>.tipso_arrow {
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble .top_right_corner,
.tipso_bubble.top_right_corner {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .bottom_right_corner,
.tipso_bubble.bottom_right_corner {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .top_left_corner,
.tipso_bubble.top_left_corner {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .bottom_left_corner,
.tipso_bubble.bottom_left_corner {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tipso.object505.com/tipso.js"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <span class="top tipso_style" data-tipso="This is a tooltip text">I want to show the tooltip on click and hide it on click as well.</span>
</div>
```

---

It seems you want to remove Tipso's default hover behavior so the tooltip *only* shows on click. One method is to use [`off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove Typso's handlers, which seem to be for "mouseover" and "mouseout" events. Then add your own click handler.

```js
// define all tips
let $tips = $('.top');

// initialize tipso and configure handlers
$tips
  .tipso()
  .off('mouseover mouseout')
  .on('click', function() {

    let $this = $(this);
    let showing = $this.hasClass('typso-showing');

    $this
      .tipso(showing ? 'hide' : 'show')
      .toggleClass('typso-showing', !showing);

  });

// close on click outside
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$tips.is(e.target)) {
    $tips.tipso('hide').removeClass('typso-showing');
  }
});
```

```css
/* Tipso Bubble Styles */

.tipso_bubble,
.tipso_bubble>.tipso_arrow {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tipso_bubble {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.tipso_style {
  cursor: help;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
}

.tipso_title {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}

.tipso_content {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0.5em;
}


/* Tipso Bubble size classes - Similar to Foundation's syntax*/

.tipso_bubble.tiny {
  font-size: 0.6rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.small {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.default {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tipso_bubble.large {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Tipso Bubble Div */

.tipso_bubble>.tipso_arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 8px solid;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.tipso_bubble.top>.tipso_arrow {
  border-top-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.bottom>.tipso_arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.left>.tipso_arrow {
  border-left-color: #000;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble.right>.tipso_arrow {
  border-right-color: #000;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.tipso_bubble .top_right_corner,
.tipso_bubble.top_right_corner {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .bottom_right_corner,
.tipso_bubble.bottom_right_corner {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .top_left_corner,
.tipso_bubble.top_left_corner {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.tipso_bubble .bottom_left_corner,
.tipso_bubble.bottom_left_corner {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://tipso.object505.com/tipso.js"></script>

<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <span class="top tipso_style" data-tipso="This is a tooltip text">I want to show the tooltip on click and hide it on click as well.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it does both. Without the hover, I wonder why you're using Tipso at all.

Comment: Because of styling capabilities and I'm using images in my tooltips. Should I rather use something else?

Comment: No, that's fine; I was just curious. I've edited my answer to remove the default hover behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much! One last thing - is it possible to make it so the tooltip hides with click anywhere? So it opens when I click on the link, but hides when I click anywhere on the page.

Comment: Updated. Also see [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it),

Answer (score 0):

Additionally how can that be made to clear one tooltip if another is clicked on in clicking outside of the first?

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4r3zybg/) shows the problem to be solved.

[image]

All code is the same as showdev's above except the html ...

```
<span class="top tipso_style" data-tipso="Tooltip one">One for tooltip</span>
<br><br>
<br><br>
<span class="top tipso_style" data-tipso="Tooltip two">Two for tooltip></span>
```

EDIT:

How about like at https://jsfiddle.net/j4r3zybg/3/ adding `$tips.tipso('hide')` after `let showing`?

```
let $this = $(this);
let showing = $this.hasClass('typso-showing');
$tips.tipso('hide')  // close all, prevent two showing
```

Nope, almost. The user now cannot copy the text easily without that tooltip disappearing before they can do ctrl-c.